# How to update weights on Scala-Graph?

Tags: scala, graph

I'm using [scala-graph](http://www.scala-graph.org/guides/core-introduction.html) for some graph computations on Scala, and I can't seem to understand how to do one simple thing: how do I update a certain weight?
Let's say I have:

```
import scalax.collection.Graph
val g = Graph(1~>2 % 1, 2~>3 % 1, 1~>3 % 3)
```

and now I'd like to create `g2` which will be the same as `g` but with `1~>2 % 2`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any native method to update the weight of an edge. What you can do is to remove an edge and add a new one with a different weight:

```
scala> g - 1~>3 % 3 + 1~>3 % 1337
res = Graph(1, 2, 3, 1~>2 %1, 1~>3 %1337, 2~>3 %1)
```

Edit: Note that the weight of the edge that is being removed, `1~>3 % <weight>`, can have any value, since edges aren't identified by their weight.

See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/scala-graph/update%7Csort:relevance/scala-graph/lG2LtfzPb0w/A4q7kBlUxNgJ) thread for more details.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without knowing the existing weight? something like `g - 1~>3 + 1~>3 % {originalWeight+1}`?

Comment: The weight of the edge you are substracting doesn't matter, you can use any value. That is because the edge is only identified by its source and destination.